# Как скрыть процесс в windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, процесс

Мне нужно запустить программу на моем компе чтобы она не отображалась в списке процессов. Не только в диспетчере задачь, но и по запросу через WinApi.

Читал что можно сделать "перехват и подмену", но на этом инфа закончилась)

Кто вкурсе этого метода, или может знает какой-то другой, подскажите плз!

Comment: Читайте про руткиты, там различные техники могут применяться

Comment: Сталкивались с какими-то? которые могут выполнить даную задачу?

Comment: что такое запрос через winapi? есть пример запроса?

Comment: у меня есть код, который скрывает из процессов, но в (details/детали) там видно останется, а в процессах нет. Надо?

Comment: https://eax.me/winapi-process-list/ - тут есть по получению списка процессов.      Код - давайте. Попробую. Моджет и этого будет достаточно

Answer (score 1):

Запускает скрытый процесс(powershell):

```
Start-Process notepad -WindowStyle Hidden
Get-Process notepad
```

Останавливает скрытый процесс:

```
Get-Process notepad | Stop-Process
```

p.s. в диспетчере в процессах не видит, видно только в details

Comment: powershell этой командой скрывает внешние признаки (панель задачь, и т.д) Процесс виден даже в диспетчере.

Comment: в диспетчере в процессах не видит,  только в details как я писал

Comment: аа.. ок. спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Винда какая? Win XP x86 - можно написать драйвер NT, работающий по принципу хуков функций (кажется, нужен хук на ZwQuerySystemInformation), и он будет работать.

На новых же, особенно x64, начинаются проблемы - требуется платная цифровая подпись для драйвера.

На Win 10 гайки затянуты особенно, но на виртуалке у меня это не проявлялось.

Comment: ну у меня 10ка. х64. В принципе могу опуститься до 7й. Есть варианты с ней какие-то?

Comment: @PavelNastoburko Вроде можно отключить проверку ц\п. Тогда есть. Но драйвера -  это для очень advanced, а не "с нуля захотел написать винлок, через неделю написал, еще через месяц написал и драйвер-руткит".